# Sending/Recieving HID reports in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, hid

I'm trying to communicate to a custom piece of hardware from a (userspace) C++ program.  The device is an HID device, but not a mouse/keyboard.

On Windows, I can use HidD_SetOutputReport to send a report, and then HidD_GetInputReport to receive the reply.   (There is more than one report being generated, but those calls let me specify which one I want.)

I'm not doing anything fancy, so it's nice and straightforward.

I am having trouble figuring out what the simple Linux alternative to those calls is.

If someone could point me towards documentation or a code example that illustrates equivalent operations on Linux, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is a HID device then for sending the HID report you need to write to the corresponding /dev/hid* device. This will be HidD_SetOutputReport alternate.

Most of the devices now using EP0 for backward communication, so for getting the response you need to read from corresponding /dev/hid* device. This will beHidD_GetInputReport alternate.

If your hardware are not using the EP0 for communication then you can find the information from your Endpoint descriptor, in which it will be defined how to get the response back.